# I wanna just add the int numbers into a LinkedList, but when i type "exit" there are an exception

Tags: java, linked-list

I wanna   add  some numbers into linked list, but in my loop when i want to end adding and type "exit" there is an exception:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "exit"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at Main.main(Main.java:16)
```

code

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Main {
        public static final String EXIT = "exit";

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            List<Integer> list = new LinkedList<>();
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            String temp;

            System.out.println("Add number: ");
            while((temp=input.nextLine()) != "exit"){
                    int i = Integer.parseInt(temp);
                    list.add(i);
                    System.out.println("Add number:");
            }
            System.out.println("Completed. The summary is: ");
            int suma = 0;
            for(Integer skl : list){
                suma += skl;
            }
            System.out.println(suma);

        }

    }
```

Comment: while((temp=input.nextLine()) != "exit"){ ERROR !!!

Use this : !"exit".equals(temp=input.nextLine())

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

```
input.nextLine() != "exit"
```

Try

```
!(input.nextLine().equals("exit"))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the classic String comparison issue.

Use:

```
 while(!"exit".equals(temp=input.nextLine()){
```